# limit the occurance of character to twice regular expression

Tags: regex

how can I write a regular expression to find elements like

```
Ab1-123456-NFTGTF
```

I tried something like

```
^([a-zA-Z0-9][^=](\-)[^=][a-zA-Z0-9][^=](\-)[^=][a-zA-Z0-9]
```

Comment: And? Which problem did you face?

Comment: Its not identifying hyphen

Comment: [a-zA-Z0-9-\-][a-zA-Z0-9-\-][a-zA-Z0-9] is working but my its taking multiple hypens between characters ex: Abc-----123456

Comment: What exactly are you trying to match or not match.

Comment: I should have 3(combination of letters and numbers) - 6numbers - 6(combination of letters and numbers)

Comment: The quantifiers are totally missing. And why do you provide [a-zA-Z0-9] when you only want to match letters as first group?

Comment: sorry I need both letters and numbers

Comment: @learner update question, not in comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I should have 3(combination of letters and numbers) - 6numbers -
>   6(combination of letters and numbers) – learner

Try following regex

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9]{3}-[0-9]{6}-[a-zA-Z0-9]{6}$
```

Comment: Wanted to post exactly the same ;)

Comment: how can I check hyphens between the characters I should have 2

Comment: @learner Did you try it? did it fail? It checks for all your needs, numbers, characters even two hyphens.